# Setting formatconditions doesn't work with certain ranges?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
        i = i + 1
        StrSearchCriteria = "=($W1=" & Chr(34) & "ETF" & Chr(34) & ")"
        With .Range("A:A").FormatConditions
            .Add Type:=2, Formula1:=StrSearchCriteria
            With .Item(i)
                .SetFirstPriority
                With .Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = RGB(225, 225, 0)
                End With
                .StopIfTrue = False
            End With
        End With
```

This does not set the format conditions.  The rule is there and the range, criteria are correct, but the format conditions are "No Format Set".

HOWEVER.... if I change

```
With .Range("A:A").FormatConditions
```

to

```
With .Range("E:E").FormatConditions
```

It works...

"B:B", "C:C", "D:D" all fail with the same issue.

Using "E:E" (and I also tried "F:F" which worked), I can then open the workbook and manually change the range to "A:A", "B:B", "C:C" or "D:D" and it works.

I then tried "A:E", which also worked.  It appears that if I use any part of column E through W (last column) it works, but if I don't include anything from E and following it fails.

Totally confused here.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is Excel all over the place, not Access, right?

Comment: @ThomasG definitely. Edited.

Comment: No, it's Access writing an Excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a merged cell range in A:D?

Comment: Yes, 'A1:B1' are merged and 'D1:L1'.  I changed the range to '"A3:A"&LastColumn', but this also fails in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

I believe @mer_curius hit on the issue - merged cells.

So, as a work around, since I only want A:A to have the coloring and I need to set the condition to A:E, I follow that rule with setting a rule with the same criteria and no-fill B:E.

The code that works looks like this:

```
        i = 1
        StrSearchCriteria = "=($W1=" & Chr(34) & "ETF" & Chr(34) & ")"
        strRange = "A:E"
        With .Range(strRange).FormatConditions
            .Add Type:=2, Formula1:=StrSearchCriteria
            With .Item(i)
                .SetFirstPriority
                With .Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = RGB(225, 225, 0)
                End With
                .StopIfTrue = False
            End With
        End With
        i = i + 1
        StrSearchCriteria = "=($W1=" & Chr(34) & "ETF" & Chr(34) & ")"
        strRange = "B:E"
        With .Range(strRange).FormatConditions
            .Add Type:=2, Formula1:=StrSearchCriteria
            With .Item(i)
                .SetFirstPriority
                With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlNone
                End With
                .StopIfTrue = False
            End With
        End With
```